# create a new entity based on the creation of another (postPersist) Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a new entity based on the creation of another. Example: I have a relationship

```
Sale <-- 1:M --> Payment
```

Now, when I persist a `Sale`, then you must create an initial `Payment` but i dont know exactly how do it.

i've try:

1. usage `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()`, `@ORM\prePersist` or `@ORM\postPersist`, but these methods does not get arguments and i can't persist the Entity `Payment`. I've even tried to relate `Sale` with  `Payment` (in prePersist method `$payment->setSale($this)`) hoping EntityManager to persist `Payment` for me. [info from here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks)
2. I tried to create a listener ([guided from here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)), but it just does not work, at no time the listener runs
3. Do it in my `SaleController::createAction()`, this way is obviously simple and it works, but this is nothing elegant and also goes against the good design of my application, this operation is part of the business logic and repeated in various parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the 3 solutions you listed 3 is still the least wrong in my opinion. It's simple, not overly complicated and easy to refactor later.

But if you're looking for a clean solution, I think what you need is a form handler or a similar service. 
Take a look at [FOSUserBundle one](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Handler/RegistrationFormHandler.php).

Basically you will create a PaymentManager class & after handling all the Sales form stuff, pass all the gathered info to PaymentManager and let it handle all the create/persist logic of Payment entity.

Comment: +1 Delegating the work to a service is simple, and keeps it DRY.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that a `PaymentManager` as suggested by @Inori is the best way to go, it is DRY and also a central point where entities are created. It allows you to marshal all the user input in the controller and then pass it onto the manager to build up the `Sale` object properly.

If you DO wish to go with the **1st** option and use a lifecycle callback I assume you are getting an exception that says an unmanaged entity was found on another entity - or something to that effect. To get around this you can cascade persist on your mapping which means that you don't need to call `persist` for the `Payment`:

```
/**
 * One-to-Many via Join Table (aka One-To-Many Unidirectional).
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Payment", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      inverseJoinColumns={
 *          @ORM\JoinColumn(unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
 *      }
 * )
 */
```

You can read more about the [One-To-One, Unidirectional](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) if it confuses you.

Also you should read about cascade persist [Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations).